# Is there a way to get the log-analytics workspace name from workspaceid using az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-log-analytics

Say I have a workspaceId cb89596-80da-421e-b495-f65aac012bfd,
can I use az CLI to get the name of the workspace from this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace list --query "[?customerId == 'cb89596-80da-421e-b495-f65aac012bfd'].name"
```

It will print the name of your Log Analytics Workspace:

```
[
  "DefaultWorkspace-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-WUS"
]
```